# Detecting a timing loop

Tags: verilog

I have the following code :

```
module Stopwatch(clk, btnC, btnU, btnR, btnL, seg, an, dp, led_left, led_right);

input   clk, btnC, btnU, btnR, btnL;
output  wire [6:0] seg;
output  wire [3:0] an;
output  wire       dp; 
output  wire [2:0] led_left;
output  wire [2:0] led_right;

wire [15:0] time_reading;
wire trig, split, reset, toggle;
wire trig_right, split_right, init_regs_right, count_enabled_right;
wire trig_left, split_left, init_regs_left, count_enabled_left;
reg selected_stopwatch; //0 is the right stopwatch and 1 is the left stopwatch

// FILL HERE INSTANTIATIONS 

Counter counter_right(clk,init_regs_right,count_enabled_right,0,time_reading[7:0]);
Counter counter_left(clk,init_regs_left,count_enabled_left,1,time_reading[15:8]);
Ctl ctl_left(clk,reset,trig_left,split_left,init_regs_left,count_enabled_left);
Ctl ctl_right(clk,reset,trig_right,split_right,init_regs_right,count_enabled_right);
Seg_7_Display display(time_reading,clk,reset,seg,an,dp);
Debouncer btnC_debouncer(clk,btnC,reset);
Debouncer btnU_debouncer(clk,btnU,trig);
Debouncer btnR_debouncer(clk,btnR,split);
Debouncer btnL_debouncer(clk,btnL,toggle);
always @(*)
begin
if (selected_stopwatch == 0 & toggle==0 )
   selected_stopwatch = 0;
else if (selected_stopwatch == 0 & toggle ==1)
   selected_stopwatch = 1;
else if (selected_stopwatch == 1 & toggle ==0)
   selected_stopwatch = 1;
else if (selected_stopwatch == 1 & toggle == 1)
   selected_stopwatch =0;
else 
   selected_stopwatch = 0;
end


assign trig_right = (selected_stopwatch == 0) & trig;
assign split_right = (selected_stopwatch == 0) & split;
assign trig_left = (selected_stopwatch == 1) & trig;
assign split_left = (selected_stopwatch == 1) & split;
assign led_right[2:0] = (selected_stopwatch==0) ? 3'b111 : 3'b000;
assign led_left [2:0] = (selected_stopwatch==1) ? 3'b111 : 3'b000;
endmodule
```

As you can see, there are many submodules and posting their code might be tedious and quite unnecessary.

As I try to implement the code, I get the following critical warnings:

[image]

I'm first interested in debugging the two lower critical warnings which are related to the HDL code written for the `Stopwatch` module. In general, this is the main module which implements two independent stopwatches, which are controlled by 4 push buttons, and their count is shown on a 7-segment display. The right one counts up, and the left one counts down. How can I debug the issue with my implementation? What's in my code generating this prohibited combinational loop?

Answer (score 2):

The code with `always @(*)` infers combinational logic:

```
always @(*)
begin
if (selected_stopwatch == 0 & toggle==0 )
   selected_stopwatch = 0;
```

The problem is that it reads from and assigns to the same signal (`selected_stopwatch`), and this creates the combinational loop.  The signal is read in the `if` condition, and it is assigned on the next line.

The documentation for your synthesis tool should provide more detailed information on the `[Synth 8-295]` message.  In fact, it looks like you can click on the hyperlink in your tool's console.

To break the timing loop, you need to adjust the design.  For example, you could make sure the `selected_stopwatch` signal is driven by sequential logic, instead of combinational logic:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (...)
        selected_stopwatch <= ...
    else ...
end
```

Comment: +1 @JustCurious Tip: this HDL code looks like software. Try to rethink it like hardware, in this case specifically an FSM with two states and one input. toolic's suggestion implements this cleanly, with both combinational and sequential code within a single "always" block.